# How do I kill Dragons?

Tags: crypt-of-the-necrodancer

I've reached Zone 3 and I'm having problems fighting Blue Dragons. If I avoid their breath and their regular attack, I don't seem to ever get a hit. If I try to attack, I either get frozen or mauled (and the dragon's attack really hurts).

I can beat them with the right gear but what do I do if I encounter them on the first level with only an iron dagger?

Comment: This wiki describes a strategy, called the Red Dragon Dance, that I've found very useful for red and blue dragons: http://crypt-of-the-necrodancer.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Dragon_Dance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important thing about dragons is they can only breathe horizontally. Standing directly above or below a Red/Blue dragon means it won't use its breath attack and will only use its melee attack on alternate beats.

Ideally you want a lot of space and no enemies nearby. With enough space, this is simple. Stand above or below and alternate between hitting and moving. The dragon moves on alternate beats so it won't hit you this way.

If you run out of space, things become a little more complicated. You need to move around the dragon and hit & run from the other side. When you're backed up against a wall, attack, then do the following. (Assuming you're below the dragon, move down instead if you were above him).

1. Move right- the dragon will try to breath attack you.
2. Move up, dodging his breath
3. Move up again (if you move left, he'll melee you)
4. Move right

You're now above the dragon. Hit him then move away. Repeat.

Comment: I think you mean they can't breathe vertically, not horizontally. Besides, the blue dragon can still hit you if you're in front and above him, as his breath is cone-shaped.

Comment: Oops. Fixed that.